# Peltiers in series protection

Tags: peltier

I would like to make a Peltier project and in order to save a little bit of money I would like to connect couple of Peltier in series directly into the power line. As far as I have read I should treat it as a diode, therefore every element should be paralleled with:

- 1000uF 25V electrolitic cap
- 1 MOhm resistor

is this protection enough?

[image]

Comment: No. keep reading....

Comment: keep reading what?

Comment: Since it is AC pick some frequency and replace all capacitors and inductors with resistors.

Comment: What gave you the wrong impression you could connect these to the grid?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 good man, I appreciate your will to help, but I have no idea what do you want me to say.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you look at cheaper and safer alternatives, like using an off-the-shelf, cheap-&-cheerful AC to DC power supply with 240/110 AC input and say 24V - 48V DC, 15A output ?? You may need to rather place the Peltiers in parallel instead of series, but “protection” is less of an issue.

Comment: well, for the price of the acdc I have 1200W of cooling, so I can cool as fast as radiator manages to reduce the heat.